# Sticky Footer pushes Content Below Page

Tags: jquery, html, css, footer, sticky-footer

i tried to setup the sticky footer from here

Here is the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/pbhE8/

And my site: http://22twenty.com/Test

As you can see the footer is being pushed beyond the base of the content.

i can't post anymore links but i'm sure you can get the css, and anything else you might need from the  site posted.

Hope someone can help

Denver

Comment: 404 error, check your link

Comment: It would help us and the rest of the community if you posted any applicable code, instead of relying on us to dive into it on your dev site.

Comment: Try to put some more effort in asking the question. Make a example on jsfiddle taht anyone can play with. Try to paste only the relevant code that has the error, so maybe you can solve the problem for yourself. Then post the jsfiddle code here into your question. It will help you and us understanding the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that what you would like to do is have that footer div stick to the bottom of the page but not overlap any content that you have in the middle of the page. I have not used 'sticky footer' before but i have done this on a few sites, this is what i do (actually came from a question i asked on here a couple of weeks ago.

create a `<div>` that is around the entire sites contents. Set the css of this div to:

```
#wrapper {
min-height: 100%;
width: 100%;
position: absolute;
}
```

The create a content div for the middle of the page where the main content of your site will go with css:

```
#maincontent {
width: 'some width';
height: 'some height';
margin-bottom: 'the height of the footer'
overflow: auto;
}
```

then have your footer div embedded within a 'bottom' div with css:

```
#bottom {
width: 100%;
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
}
```

Then as long as the margin of the main content div is the same height as your footer div they will not overlap but the footer will be inside the 'bottom' div which is 'stuck' to the bottom of the browser window.

Hope this helps let me know if you have any questions or need further help.

Comment: can i use for #maincontent height:100%? or not give it one?

Comment: If you take a look now ive done what you said here: http://22twenty.com/Test and its no change:(

Comment: Yes the `#maincontent` height can be what ever you like, during testing i usually have a static height of ~600px to mimic content otherwise it will inherit a height of 0, its hard to determine your error without code but your bottom div has no `position:abolsute` or `bottom:0` css which is why its not at the bottom and your problem is you have 2 `grid_12.text-right` divs one with height 15 one with height 26, giving total height of 41px but your bottom and footer divs only have height 20px, set the height of bottom and footer to 41px then set `#maincontent {margin-bottom:41px}` to stop overlap

Comment: go here and inspect element look at my code, klstuff.com (ignore the yellow box that is for something else).

Comment: well i reset the height, and its up but its as though theres a padding below the footer, i looked at you page and i can't really tell what is different. 

thanks

Comment: @Denver I have looked at your site and now that the CSS matches what i have put i  can't see the problem, the footer is at the bottom,  when the browser is resized it 'sticks' to the bottom if the browser is resized to less than the size of the content the footer does not overlap. Could you explain what is still wrong? are you talking about the tiny 4px gap between the very bottom of the window and the bottom of your `row` div?thats because your `bottom`&`footer` height are 60px and the bottom margin of content is 60px (which is great) but your `row` div is only 56px giving 4px spare at bottom

Comment: @Denver If you are finding this information helpful could you please up vote the comments and or answer, also tick the answer as correct if it actually was useful. Thanks

Comment: Well, ive lowered the size of the box so you can see the footer still pushes down below the bottom. I set the footer to 56 and the magin-bottom:56px and still pushing down

And i can't up vote as i just joined.

Comment: Ok no problem. I have had another look at it hasn't changed, have you uploaded an update? What browser are you using? I have looked in chrome, firefox and safari all of which look fine, there is no overlap of any divs and they all work as you would expect. Maybe i am misunderstanding your problem.

Comment: It doesn't push below the bottom of the page for you? even without content example: imgur.com/0YEw5 – Denver 10 mins ago

Comment: Ahhhh now i see what you mean, thats because you have a margin of 20px on your body tag. take that away and it fixes the problem.

Comment: removed and its still not perfect any ideas?

Comment: Do you think its another padding or margin thing?

Comment: nvm fixed it you were a great help!